# Wordpress - adding other functionality to post-adding panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to learn WordPress CMS theme developing, and I've came across an issue that i can't overcome with my knowledge.

What i'd like to do is do allow end-user to attach few downloadable files to the post and attach few images that will be used for a slider gallery.

The problem is i don't want the user to mess with the code, perfect solution would be adding a new panels on the right with those functions.

What is the correct approach to extend post adding functionality, where should I start with? Functions.php? Or does it require Wordpress' core changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both the downloadable files as well as the images for the slider you can use the WordPress media library already on the post/page editing screen. Problem is differentiating between the uploaded media items.

If you want to add custom file upload fields to the post editing screen of WordPress, you can add a custom metabox with one or more fields for the author to upload or input and then save/capture those values and files by hooking to the `save_post` hook. Here are the steps:

1. Hook to `add_meta_boxes` action hook to a function of yours and use `add_meta_box()` function to display your custom meta box/es.
2. In your output of `add_meta_box()` simply display an HTML file upload field.
3. Hook to the `save_post` action hook in WordPress to save/capture the file uploaded.
4. You can use `update_post_meta()` to save the file's details as meta/custom field to the post so that you can reuse it later inside the post itself.

Here is a good tutorial with step by step instructions: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1--wp-22291

Answer (score 2):

You can modify literally everything in Wordpress without changing core. 
What you want can be ran trough functions.php.

This tutorial pretty much covers everything you need:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/
Its under 'plugins' but all those actions are accessible in functions.php too.

But if your new I would recommend a plugin like ACF (advanced custom fields), you'll get the job done faster.

ACF packs a bunch of fields but, if none meet your needs, creating a plugin for a new type of field is not very hard (if you got some knowledgement on php functions).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few answers to this - the best way would to either add a [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) or to use an external plugin (recommend ACF - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) - this way you can extend post data on certain post types or pages and display them dynamically in your theme.